# What does: throw 0 do/mean? Is it "bad"?

Tags: c++, exception

#### Context

I came across some code, like this:

```
if( Some_Condition ) throw 0;
```

I googled a bit, and found a few other code snippets using that odd looking `throw 0` form.

I presume one would catch this as:

```
catch(const int& e) 
{  }
```

Or is this a NULL ptr? to be caught as `void*` ?

#### Question

What does this `throw 0` do? Is it special in some way?

My normal preference would be to throw something that is (or derived from) `std::exception`. So to me this looks "bad".
Is it "bad" ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally throw can throw any type, any you need to catch it with this type or its base type.

So technically it is legal code but...

**it is bad code:** You should always derive your exceptions from `std::exception` or at least from some class that provides some useful information about error rather then plain number. But deriving from `std::exception` is **the** correct way because it allows to use topmost `catch(std::exception const &e)` and get at least some information about the error.

Answer (score 4):

It is not special, you can thow int just as an exception class.

It is considered a poor style, because an exception class can tell more about what actually happened.

Answer (score 3):

It's an int.
It is "bad", since throwing 0 makes the code unreadable, or hints someone is using exceptions as a value returning system.
(It's basically the same problem as a magic number inside the code)

NULL is defined as `((void *)0)`. If the compiler sees a 0 it means an int. It may be automatically casted to something else, but only if there's a reason (For example assignment to double). The line `throw 0` does not give such a reason, so an int is thrown.

Comment: `((void*)0)` is not a valid definition for NULL in C++.

Comment: Could you catch `0` with `catch (void* ex)` or similar?

Comment: No - 0 has type `int`. Since `int` has no base classes, you must catch it as `int`, `int const&`, or `...`.