# "Throw NULL" statement in C

Tags: c, null, goto, throw

I'm trying to learn some codes. and I found Throw NULL; statements.

It looks like

```
static void function(something)  
{    
  some variables;
  if(a.size > b.size) {
       Throw NULL;
  }
  ...more another codes
}
```

I'm not even sure Throw Null; is heading for..

Looks like goto() statement, but with throwing values..

Is it normal? I mean, of course codes are working, and I'm not an experienced man but haven't seen like this.(sorry for noobs talking)

Comment: Can show what's in "some variables" please

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does: throw 0 do/mean? Is it "bad"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628677/what-does-throw-0-do-mean-is-it-bad)

Comment: @PreetSangha Nothing for special in variables.

Comment: @PreetSangha just some 'int a; static int b; File fr;' something like that.

Comment: There is no support for `try/throw/catch` in C. `Throw` in your code is most likely a proprocessor macro that uses `setjmp` and `longjmp` to emulate `try/throw/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* standard C but looks to be something that emulates an exception mechanism in the language (something that can be done with `setjmp/longjmp`, for example).

The best bet would be to look at the preprocessor output (such as that obtained by `gcc -E`) to see what it actually turns that into.

Alternatively, follow the header file inclusions since one of those will almost certainly provide this emulation.