# Throw(NULL) unrecognized

Tags: c++, null, clang

In a C++ program, is there another word than `NULL`, `null` or `nullptr`, because `throw(NULL)` returns an error :

> **../../test.cpp:6:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'NULL'** : `throw(NULL);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628677/what-does-throw-0-do-mean-is-it-bad

maybe this can help you

Comment: You're supposed to throw an object that conveys the problem that caused the exception to the calling code. What does `NULL` convey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to use NULL**
NULL isn't actually part of the core C or C++ language. It is defined in  `cstddef` or `stddef.h`.

On the other hand [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) onwards, `nullptr` is a keyword and doesn't require a header. Since you're using C++, prefer nullptr, which is a keyword, and typed.

---

**How to use throw**
Avoid throwing `NULL` or `nullptr` and prefer throwing object of class that is derived from std::exception.

Comment: Of course, `throw nullptr;` can only be caught with `catch ( std::nullptr_t )`.  Which can't catch anything else.  I seriously doubt that that's a good idea either.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes you are very right. I tried to answer how to use `NULL` but never advocated to use it for throw. I would add to my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is a macro, defined in `stddef.h` or `cstddef`; you have to
include one of these files to get it.

But the real question is: do you want to?  Exceptions are caught by
type, and the type of `NULL` isn't specified.  It must be an integral
type, but it can be any integral type; in practice, I've only seen `int`
and `long`, but all of the others are possible.  So how are you going to
catch it?

Answer (score 0):

If this is your code, throw whatever you're catching.

Here's an example, with int 0, from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/

```
int main () {
  try
  {
    throw 20;
  }
  catch (int e)
  {
    cout << "An exception occurred. Exception Nr. " << e << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avoid throwing an `int` and prefer an object of class that is derived from `std::exception`

Answer (score 0):

While you should be able to throw any of (`NULL`, `null`, `nullptr`), you might ask yourself what you're trying to accomplish.  NULL usually resolves to an integer defined as 0.  This leads to occasional confusion and unexpected results, and is exactly why in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) the `nullptr` keyword came to be.  It is a distinct type to represent a null pointer that won't get confused with integers.

If you're trying to throw and catch integers, `throw( 0 );`.  If you're trying to throw and catch null pointers, `void* p = nullptr; throw( p );`.

The keyword `nullptr` need no includes to work.  `NULL`, on my linux box, is defined in stddef.h.

This sample code snip might illustrate:

```
try {
    throw( NULL );
}
catch( long e ) {
    cout << "caught long " << e << endl;
}


try {
    void* p = nullptr;
    throw( p );
}
catch( long e ) {
    cout << "caught long " << e << endl;
}
catch( void* p ) {
    cout << "caught ptr" << endl;
}
catch( ... ) {
    cout << "caught unk" << endl;
}
```

The output is:
`caught long 0
caught ptr`